# How to reomve Column from Column header menu

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid and in column I am using `menuDisabled : false` because of that I am getting header menu. As shown in menu.

[image: Picture]

I want to remove Column but not getting any hold or any config by which I can by  do that. Can any body please suggest me how to remove column from menu header?

Comment: Not sure how to do it in Ext 3, but in Ext 4 I override getColumnMenu function of the Ext.grid.header.Container class. Maybe [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fo8) fiddle can give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for comment. In your fiddle column is still there in column header menu.

Comment: Guess I misunderstood the question (thought you want to remove the column from the columns menu). So what are you actually trying to hide (would be nice if you can show some code)?

Comment: @Zoran Thanks a ton to reply. I got the solution. It is easy on newer version but in older it is bit tough. Many Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Override the Grid Column and set **hideable: false**

```
Ext.define('overrides.grid.column.Column', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',

    hideable: false,         // Whether the column should be hideable.

    // Initializes the component.
    // @override
    //
    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```